# pcre regex match nth occurence

Tags: regex, pcre

*This is **not** a duplicate. I have checked before asking.*

I have this string separated with `|` and I want to match the **nth** element.

```
aaaaaaaaa aaa|bb bbbbb|cccc ccccccc|ddd ddddddd|aaa aaa aaaaa|zzz zzz zzzzzzz
```

The closer I got is using this pattern but it buggy:

```
([^\|]*\|){2}[^\|]*
```

https://regex101.com/r/EYZbK5/1

This is plain **pcre**. In this context, javascript such `.split()` cannot be used.

Say I want to get the 3rd element `cccc ccccccc` what regex should I use?

Comment: This seems to be an exact duplicate. Please see the marked question and if it didn't provide you an answer then edit accordingly.

Comment: Well, the accepted answer really suggests using a capturing group. Since the answer accepted suggest the same solution, it is really a dupe, as you are not interested in PCRE specific options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an anchor to assert the start of the line and then repeat not matching  a `|` followed by a `|` 2 times. Then capture the third part in a capturing group which will contain `cccc ccccccc`

`^(?:[^|]*\|){2}([^|]*)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ERMBZn/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the line
- `(?:` Start non capturing group

  - `[^|]*\|` Match not a `|` using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) zero or more times followed by a `|`.
- `){2}` close non capturing group and repeat that 2 times
- `([^|]*)` Capture in a group matching not a `|` zero or more times

Answer (score 4):

You may use

```
^(?:[^|]*\|){2}\K[^|]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EYZbK5/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^|]*\|){2}` - a [**non-capturing group**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) matching two consecutive occurrences of

  - `[^|]*` - a [**negated character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching 0+ chars other than `|`
  - `\|` - a `|` char
- `\K` - [**match reset operator**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) that discards the text matched so far
- `[^|]*` - 0+ chars other than `|`.

To avoid empty string matches, you may replace the last `[^|]*` with `[^|]+`.

Answer (score 2):

you may try this and take group2

```
(\|?(.*?)(?:\|)){3}
```

[demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/EYZbK5/5)

Comment: This matches `cccc ccccccc|` including the `|`

Comment: also it doesn't get the last '`zzz zzz zzzzzzz`'

Comment: oh sorry, updated and he can take group2